# variable not found in php

Tags: php, arrays, session

i passed an array to another page using session 
i also passed an index of array 
now i want to access that particular index but i am not able to do so can anybody help

here is he first page where i have created the array and stored it in session

```
<?php

//connection made
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "QSTNS");
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

//-----------------two variables entered in datavbase------------
$user = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['user']);
$user1 = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['user1']);

$sql = "INSERT INTO student (name,rln,scr)VALUES ('$user1','$user','0')";
if (!mysqli_query($con, $sql)) {
    die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
}

$res = mysqli_query($con, 'SELECT COUNT(*) FROM qstns');
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($res);
echo $row[0];

$size = $row[0];

//creating an array of size equal to number of questions in DATABASE....
$q_indx = array(); //question indexes without permutation 
$attmpt = array(); //check if a question attempted or not
$score = array();  //score per question initially empty    

for ($i = 0; $i < $size; $i++) {
    array_push($q_indx, $i);
    array_push($attmpt, -1);
    array_push($score, 0);
}

$cindx = 0;

session_start();
$_SESSION['q_indx'] = $q_indx;             //HERE THAT SESSION IS CREATED
$_SESSION['attmpt'] = $attmpt;
$_SESSION['score'] = $score;
$_SESSION['cindx'] = $cindx;

header('Location: quiz_start.php');
mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

here is the quiz_start.php

```
<?php
       session_start();

      $con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","QSTNS");
        if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
         echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
          }

       $dslpy=$_SESSION['q_indx'][$_SESSION['cindx']] ;
          echo $dsply ;
          //$qstn = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM qstns where qid = '". $dsply[0] 

           ."'");

            //echo $qstn['qname'] . '\n';

          mysqli_close($con);
          ?>
```

it is giving error dsply variable not found
can any body help ?

Comment: Shouldnt your SQL be "SELECT * FROM qstns where qid = '{$dsply[0]}'"?

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong but what you want to accomplish here is access `cindx` which is an integer (index) of the `q_indx` array both of which are stored in session variables? If yes, then you could do something like : `$_SESSION['q_indx'][$_SESSION['cindx']]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [this script](https://eval.in/200611), we can gather that `$_SESSION['q_indx']` holds an array of numbers, as below;

```
Array
(
    [0] => 0
    [1] => 1
    [2] => 2
    [3] => 3
    [4] => 4
)
```

From your code, `$cindx = 0;`, so we are looking at index `0`. Therefore,

```
echo $_SESSION['q_indx'][0];  //One way of doing it
echo $_SESSION['q_indx'][$cindx];  //Another way of doing it
```

---

**EDIT**

> *Cannot use object of type mysqli_result as array in C:\wamp\www\quiiz_portal\quiz_start.php on line 12 can u tell why it there*

Change your MySQL query to become

```
$qstn = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM qstns where qid = '". $dsply[0] ."'");
```

---

**EDIT**

You are missing `session_start();` from your first file.

Comment: @hd  i tried it and it produces another error 
Cannot use object of type mysqli_result as array in C:\wamp\www\quiiz_portal\quiz_start.php on line 12

can u tell why it there

Comment: That error doesn't stem from here. I will update my answer to fix that for you

Comment: @hd i have editd the query please can u tell whats going wrong i am a novice in php

Comment: You don't have `session_start();` in your first file.

Comment: You do, but make it just after the opening php tag.

Comment: @hd 10x a lot buddy for your help n dsply was not found because i typed dslpy initially.